# Make SKScene fill whole screen using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I have the following in `GameViewController.swift`

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        println(self.view.frame.size)
        var skView:SKView = self.view as SKView
        if skView.scene == nil {
            skView.showsFPS = false
            skView.showsNodeCount = false

            // Create and configure the scene.
            var scene : SKScene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
            scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill

            // Present the scene.
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

it prints :

```
(320.0,480.0)
```

How to make the `GameScene` fill the whole screen instead of leaving black bands at the top and bottom of the screen?

the code in `GameScene.swift`

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        var background : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "background.png")
        background.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)
        self.addChild(background)
    }
}
```

`background.png` is an image of size `640x1138`

The deployment target is iOS 7.1

I am using Xcode 6.0.1 (Beta)

Comment: Did you solve this already?

Comment: Yes @MarkusRautopuro , I answered my question below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to manually add an image set named `LauchImage` in the `Images.xcassets`.

Comment: This reads as if you just added a file to a project folder and that solved the problem.  I have the same issue and managed to solve it by adding a button in another view (absolutely no clue why that works) but I was hoping for a better solution since I don't need the button.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add a Launch Screen:

> New File - iOS - User Interface - Launch Screen

2. Set the name of your new launch screen in:

> Project - General - Launch Screen File

3. In GameViewController set

> sceneNode.scaleMode = .resizeFill

Comment: Can you possibly explain why adding a launch screen fixes content filling for the whole app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize your background node to match scene.

```
background.size = self.frame.size
```

Comment: `scene` is a variable in `GameViewController.swift` , `background` is in `GameScene.swift`

Answer (score 0):

**First go onto your Xcode project**

click the **.xcodeproj** file

[image]

Then under deployment info there should be a checkbox that says requires full screen check this and then the whole screen should be used!

**EDIT**

You must also assign a launch screen it as it was full screen for me momentarily but stopped once I removed the launch screen, you can assign It just under the deployment info it is under

**App Icons and Launch Images**

even if you haven't created one Xcode usually creates one for you when you first make the project it should be under the name "main"